# Call another Controllers method in the current Controller in Typo3

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3

I have created an extension using Jbuilder , the purpose of this extension is to list out all countries and the addresses that belong to each country , so in the Jbuilder frontend I created 2 Models , Country and Address and I designed a (1--*) relation .

I could list the countries in a page , but I don't know how to list the Adresses in the same page , I don't know how to call Address's methods inside the listAction of the Country Controller ..

```
    public function listAction() {
    $lands = $this->landRepository->findAll();
    $this->view->assign('lands', $lands);
   }
```

Could somebody help me please .. I am new to typo3 and extensions .

Comment: Jbuilder is an extension in typo3 that helps you to create your own extension , so it's often called extensions builder

Comment: You mean the extension_builder as in http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder ?

Comment: yep .. that's what I meant

Comment: Where do you get the J from? It sounds like Joomla somehow. Just wondering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject your address repo in your controller:

```
  /**
     * addressRepository
     *
     * @var \Vendor\Extkey\Domain\Repository\addressRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $addressRepository;
```

and use it

```
  public function listAction() {
    $this->view->assign('lands', $this->landRepository->findAll() );
    $this->view->assign('addressses', $this->addressRepository->findAll()) ;

   }
```

Comment: hey thanks for that tip , I did it exactly , but now when I refreshed the page , it's displaying a blank page ( deleted the caches ) ... I checked the files , and guess what , the file "AddressRepository.php" was not in the Repository folder , only "Landrepository" is to be found , so I created it and injected it as well in the AddressController , but still get the blank page .. what do you think the problem is due to ?

Comment: If you get a blank page: OR add error messages to your output OR take a look at your error log. This will tell you what your problem is.

Comment: ok , and where I'm supposed to find that error_log file ? if you meant the file \typo3temp\logs\typo3.log it's empty ...

Comment: Inside INSTALL TOOL, you can switch the mode of your instance. Like whether 'Live Mode' or 'Debug Mode'. Debug Mode helps you to see the errors in frontend. It's safe to switch to debug mode unless it's a commercial production. Check what's the message shown.